# Matching form data with multidimensional array

Tags: php

What validation code should I use to return a FALSE when  ALL the data received via

**$_GET['group'],**

**$_GET['chapter']**

**$_GET['article']**

does NOT MATCH with the **$laws[$group][$chapter][$article]** Multidimensional array already set?

I ask because I intend to echo back one article at a time in **$laws multidimensional array**, for which if such an array construction does not exist, an error returns.

Thanks a lot!

```
    <?php

session_start();
$laws = array(
    "group1" => array(
        "1" => array(
            "1" => "This is article (1) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
            "2" => "This is article (2) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
            "3" => "This is article (3) in chapter (1) of (group1)",
        ),
        "2" => array(
            "1" => "This is article (1) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
            "2" => "This is article (2) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
            "3" => "This is article (3) in chapter (2) of (group1)",
        ),
    ),
    "group2" => array(
        "1" => array(
            "1" => "This is article (1) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
            "2" => "This is article (2) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
            "3" => "This is article (3) in chapter (1) of (group2)",
        ),
        "2" => array(
            "1" => "This is article (1) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
            "2" => "This is article (2) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
            "3" => "This is article (3) in chapter (2) of (group2)",
        ),
    )
);


$_SESSION['group'] = $_GET['group'];
$_SESSION['chapter'] = $_GET['chapter'];
$_SESSION['article'] = $_GET['article'];

$group = $_SESSION['group'];
$chapter = $_SESSION['chapter'];
$article = $_SESSION['article'];



// Echo Article from $laws multidimensional Array

echo $laws[$group][$chapter][$article];
?>
```

Comment: THANKS FOR SHOUTING YOUR TITLE. I WAS FALLING ASLEEP BUT NOW I'M AWAKE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return FALSE when ALL the data received does not match:

```
$grp= $_GET['group'];
$chap = $_GET['chapter'];
$art = $_GET['article'];
return isset($laws[$grp]) || isset($laws[$grp][$chap]) || isset($laws[$grp][$chap][$art]);
```

But I think you want to return FALSE when ANY of the data received does not match, you should then use:

```
return isset($laws[$grp][$chap][$art]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if the given article exists in the given group and chapter use isset() http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php:

```
$article_exists = isset($laws[$group][$chapter][$article];
```